# iOSアプリでボイスで録音したm4aかwavの音声データをmp4などの動画に変更。

Tags: swift, ios

iOSアプリでボイスで録音したm4aかwavの音声データをmp4などの動画に変更してTwitterやInstagramでシェアをしたいのですが変換方法をご存知の方は教えていただきたいです。
App StoreにMotiv Audioというアプリがあり、そのアプリでは録音した音声(wav)をmp4ファイルに変換してカメラロールに保存できる仕組みがあるので可能とは思いますが、いい方法やアドバイスがあれば教えていただきたいです。

Answer (score -1):

取り急ぎの回答ですが、lameが使用可能だと思います。

[lame＋AVAudioEngine MP3フォーマットでの録音, Swift 4](https://jp.ubunifu.co/development/lame%EF%BC%8Bavaudioengine-mp3%E3%83%95%E3%82%A9%E3%83%BC%E3%83%9E%E3%83%83%E3%83%88%E3%81%A7%E3%81%AE%E9%8C%B2%E9%9F%B3-swift-4)

Comment: 質問としては音声ファイル(m4a, wav)から**動画**ファイル(mp4)に変換したいようです。LAMEだと音声ファイルの変換(エンコード)しかできないかと。